# Inductive types carrying proofs

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

There is this one exercise in "Software Foundations" that I've been trying to solve correctly for some time now but I've actually hit a wall in terms of trying to write down the function being asked for. Here is the relevant part of the exercise

> Consider a different, more efficient representation of natural numbers
>   using a binary rather than unary system. That is, instead of saying
>   that each natural number is either zero or the successor of a natural
>   number, we can say that each binary number is either
>
> - zero,
> - twice a binary number, or
> - one more than twice a binary number.
>
> (a) First, write an inductive definition of the type bin corresponding
>   to this description of binary numbers.

The naive definition doesn't quite work because you end up being able to construct terms that add 1 to a number that already had 1 added to it or multiplying zero with 2 for no good reason. In order to avoid those I figured I would encode some kind of state transition into the constructors to avoid those but this is kinda tricky so this was the best I could come up with

```
Inductive tag : Type := z | nz | m. (* zero | nonzero | multiply by 2 *)

Inductive bin_nat : tag -> Type :=
  (* zero *)
  | Zero : bin_nat z
  (* nonzero *)
  | One : bin_nat nz
  (* multiply by 2 -> nonzero *)
  | PlusOne : bin_nat m -> bin_nat nz
  (* nonzero | multiply by 2 -> multiply by 2 *)
  | Multiply : forall {t : tag}, (t = m \/ t = nz) -> bin_nat t -> bin_nat m.
```

With the above representation I avoid the issues of terms that don't make sense but now I have to carry around proofs whenever I multiply by 2. I actually have no idea how to use these things in recursive functions though.

I know how to construct the proofs and the terms and they look like this

```
(* nonzero *)
Definition binr (t : tag) := or_intror (t = m) (eq_refl nz).
(* multiply by 2 *)
Definition binl (t : tag) := or_introl (t = nz) (eq_refl tag m).
(* some terms *)
Check Zero.
Check One.
Check (Multiply (binr _) One).
Check (Multiply (binl _) (Multiply (binr _) One)).
Check PlusOne (Multiply (binl _) (Multiply (binr _) One)).
```

I can also write down a "proof" of the theorem that I want to correspond to a function but I don't know how to actually convert it to a function. Here's the proof for the conversion function

```
Definition binary_to_nat : forall t : tag, bin_nat t -> nat.
Proof.
intros.
einduction H as [ | | b | t proof b ].
  { exact 0. } (* Zero *)
  { exact 1. } (* One *)
  { exact (S (IHb b)). } (* PlusOne *)
  { (* Multiply *)
    edestruct t.
    cut False.
    intros F.
    case F.
    case proof.
    intros F.
    inversion F.
    intros F.
    inversion F.
    exact (2 * (IHb b)).
    exact (2 * (IHb b)).
  }
Defined.
```

I know this term is the function I want because I can verify that I get the right answers when I compute with it

```
Section Examples.

Example a : binary_to_nat z Zero = 0.
Proof.
lazy.
trivial.
Qed.

Example b : binary_to_nat nz One = 1.
Proof.
lazy.
trivial.
Qed.

Example c : binary_to_nat m ((Multiply (binl _) (Multiply (binr _) One))) = 4.
Proof.
lazy.
trivial.
Qed.

End Examples.
```

So finally the question, is there an easy way to convert the above proof term to an actual function in a simple way or do I have to try to reverse engineer the proof term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like your idea of representing a valid binary number using states and an indexed inductive type. However, as the question indicates, it's possible to get away with just three constructors on the inductive type: zero, multiply by 2, and multiply by 2 and add one. That means that the only transition we need to avoid is multiplying zero by 2.

```
Inductive tag : Type := z | nz. (* zero | nonzero *)

Inductive bin_nat : tag -> Type :=
  (* zero *)
  | Zero : bin_nat z
  (* multiply by 2 *)
  | TimesTwo : bin_nat nz -> bin_nat nz
  (* multiply by 2 and add one *)
  | TimesTwoPlusOne : forall {t : tag}, bin_nat t -> bin_nat nz.
```

Then, for example,

```
Let One := TimesTwoPlusOne Zero. (* 1 *)
Let Two := TimesTwo One. (* 10 *)
Let Three := TimesTwoPlusOne One. (* 11 *)
Let Four := TimesTwo Two. (* 100 *)
```

So `TimesTwo` adds a zero to the end of the binary representation and `TimesTwoPlusOne` adds a one.

**If you want to try this yourself, don't look any further.**

(I would have put this in spoiler tags, but apparently code blocks in spoiler tags are glitchy)

Incrementing a binary number.

```
Fixpoint bin_incr {t: tag} (n: bin_nat t): bin_nat nz :=
match n with
| Zero => One
| TimesTwo n' => TimesTwoPlusOne n'
| @TimesTwoPlusOne _ n' => TimesTwo (bin_incr n')
end.
```

A helper definition for converting `nat` to binary.

```
Definition nat_tag (n: nat): tag :=
match n with
| 0 => z
| S _ => nz
end.
```

Converting `nat` to binary.

```
Fixpoint nat_to_bin (n: nat): bin_nat (nat_tag n) :=
match n with
| 0 => Zero
| S n' => bin_incr (nat_to_bin n')
end.
```

Converting binary to `nat`. Note that this uses the notations for multiplication and addition of natural numbers. If this doesn't work, you may not have the right scopes open.

```
Fixpoint bin_to_nat {t: tag} (n: bin_nat t): nat :=
match n with
| Zero => 0
| TimesTwo n' => 2 * (bin_to_nat n')
| @TimesTwoPlusOne _ n' => 1 + 2 * (bin_to_nat n')
end.
```

We get actual functions from these definitions (note that 20 is 10100 in binary).

```
Compute nat_to_bin 20.
= TimesTwo
     (TimesTwo (TimesTwoPlusOne (TimesTwo (TimesTwoPlusOne Zero))))
 : bin_nat (nat_tag 20)

Compute bin_to_nat (nat_to_bin 20).
= 20
 : nat
```

One further technical note. I used this code on two versions of Coq (8.6 and 8.9+alpha) and one version demanded that I put the tag in explicitly when matching on `TimesTwoPlusOne`, while the other allowed it to stay implicit. The above code should work in either case.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks for taking the time to unpack it.